# angularjs: saving multiple students at the same time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am trying to save number of students at the time,i wrote the following code but i did not know where to go further. any more info or links to resources regarding this topic would be much appreciated
what i have done so far :

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <fieldset data-ng-repeat="student in students"> 
        <input type="text" ng-model="student.class" name="" placeholder="Class Name ">                
        <input type="text" ng-model="student.firstname" name="" placeholder="First Name ">
        <input type="text" ng-model="student.lastname" name="" placeholder="Last Name ">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeStudent()">-</button>
    </fieldset>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addNewStudent()">New Student</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="save()">Save</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>                
 </div>
```

the controller is:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $modalInstance, $students) {
    $scope.students = [];

    $scope.addNewStudent = function() {
        $scope.students.push({
            classname: "",
            firstname: "",
            lastname: ""
        });
    };
    $scope.removeStudent = function() {
        var lastItem = $scope.students.length - 1;
        $scope.students.splice(lastItem);
    };

    $scope.save = function() {
        $modalInstance.close($scope.students);
    };

    $scope.delete = function() {
        $scope.students['deleted'] = 1;
        $modalInstance.close($scope.students);
    };

    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
});
```

in the view i can write the infos of students but when i click save button it only save the first student

modal instance:

```
    $scope.openStudent = function (student) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'modalStudent.html',
        controller: 'mainCTRL',
        windowClass:'app-modal-window',
        resolve: {
            students: function () {
                var students= {};

                if (student !== undefined){
                    students['classname'] = student.classname; 
                    students['firstname'] = student.firstname ; 
                    students['lastname'] = student.lastname; 
                    students['nachname'] = student.nachname; 

                }
                console.log("studinfo",students);
                return students;
            }
        }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (students) {

        if (students.deleted  === undefined || students.deleted == 0) { 
            oStudent = { classname: students.classname, 
                        firstname: students.firstname, 
                        lastname: students.lastname,
                        delete_time:"0000-00-00 00:00:00"
                        };

            saveStudent( $indexedDB,Student).then( function(id) {
                $scope.buildMenu();
            });
        } else {
             oStudent = { id: students.id,
                        delete_time:new Date().toISOString()
                        };
            deleteStudent( $indexedDB, $scope, students.id).then( function(id) {
                saveStudent( $indexedDB, Student, $scope.selectedUser.id ).then( function(id) {
                $scope.buildMenu();
            });
            });
        }
    }, function () {
        //console.log('Modal Student dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
}
```

Comment: all the students are pushed to `$scope.students`.  What is the use of `$modalInstance` here?

Comment: sorry i forgot to post modalinstance i updated the code it is my appcontroller i pass existing students to this modal , mainCtrl control only the veiw of adding new student

Answer (score 0):

In case its a modal where you are passing the existing students objects, your controller code should be modified as:

Also you should use two separate views in this case for add and edit to avoid code cluttering. Because in case of addition students will be an array of objects and in case of edit it will be a single object where you cannot use ng-repeat as it wont work

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $modalInstance, students) {

    //students variable contains information about the student to be edited, so your code should be something like this
    if(students.classname !== undefined){
         $scope.students = students;   
    }else{
         $scope.students = [];
    }
```

// rather than re-initializing each time modal gets opened you should retain value from students that you are passing

```
    $scope.addNewStudent = function() {
        $scope.students.push({
            classname: "",
            firstname: "",
            lastname: ""
        });
    };
    $scope.removeStudent = function() {
        var lastItem = $scope.students.length - 1;
        $scope.students.splice(lastItem);
    };

     $scope.save = function() {
        $modalInstance.close($scope.students);
         //make sure to save this when modal closes in the variable you are returning students from when modal is triggered
    };

    $scope.delete = function() {
        $scope.info['deleted'] = 1;
        $modalInstance.close($scope.students);
    };

    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
});
```

Comment: i update my code and added the modal instance can pleas have a look at it

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in the above code in resolve and .then(), can you please explain?

Comment: in the main view i have 2 buttons 1 to edit student and the other one to add new student , both button uses the same view mentioned tin the above code . when it is new student all text view are empty and when editing a student those fields will be containing the data of student (resolve ).when clicking save  a new student the it is saved and the edit view is closed and the student view reload to with new student(s)

Comment: Check my edit. Just for the student add and edit controller

Comment: did not work, thanks Rahul for your help, maybe you or someone else have an example about saving more than one student at a time to the database, i have been using angularjs since 6 months, now i face this problem and  i looked a lot in internet but i could not find anything helpful , everything is about adding 1 record only